# BizTalk Sendport WS Secure OASIS WCF Custom and Behavior

Tags: c#, biztalk, oasis, soap1.2, send-port

I have a BizTalk app that is currently using the WCF-Custom Adapter.

The config Sendport, the problem is that only the body and the TimeStamp have to be signed and the messageProtectionOrder property does not allow the only signature. I need behavior to just sign the body and Timestamp.

Can some help?

Solution proposed by me and shared

Hi all

Perform a custom sendport by hand that is functional with a behavior that determines the protectionlevel.

I want to share it with everyone, as it seems necessary.

For a WS Secure with only signature, you can change the Ws model with the messageSecurityVersion parameter.

The behavior is necessary, whoever wants to ask for it.

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/emrkjFTa
```

[messagesecurityversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityversion?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This looks like it might be a customer support question, see "[Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)"

Comment: Have you looked at writing a custom end point behavior?